# Configuring Omnet on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, omnet++, macos-sierra

I use Omnet for a course at university and had no problem setting it up on Windows 10, however setting it up on Mac OSX is returning this error

https://i.gyazo.com/e04b401281323c5b70cdf896b18b5330.png

I don't have either of those bash files, any advice or help would be appreciated! thank-you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before configuring and building OMNET type

```
. setenv
```

into your shell (i.e. source the setenv script in the root folder of omnetpp. That will set up you path). After that you can configure and then build.